# Replace JSON node values with one of their specific child node value - node JS

Tags: node.js, json, express, recursion

I have this JSON object, and I would like to replace all 'title' and 'description' objects with
title.es and description.es child values, somehow like this: item.title = item.title.es
Could you help me to find the correct recursive algorithm?
I tried to use recursive functions, but didn't worked.

```
[
  {
    "name": "aaa",
    "title": {
      "es": "dfghfdghgfhgfh",
      "en": "hjklhjkljkhljkhlklj"
    },
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "aaa-1",
        "title": {
          "es": "dfgdfgsdfg",
          "en": "dfghfgdhgfhgfhgf"
        },
        "services": [
          {
            "name": "aaa-1-1",
            "title": {
              "es": "dfghgfhfghgfdh",
              "en": "dfghfgdhfgdhgfdh"
            }
            "description": {
              "es": "sdfgfdsgfdg",
              "en": "sertztrezrteztre"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "aaa-2",
        "title": {
          "es": "ertzrtez",
          "en": "ertuztzutzuztuzt"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bbb",
    "title": {
      "es": "sdfsdfdsf",
      "en": "sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf"
    },
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "bbb-1",
        "title": {
          "es": "sdfsdfdsfdsf",
          "en": "sdfdsfdsfds"
        },
        "services": [
          {
            "name": "bbb-1-1",
            "title": {
              "es": "werwerewrewr",
              "en": "werwerwerwerew"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "bbb-1-2",
            "title": {
              "es": "werewrewrwerewr",
              "en": "werewrewrewrwerwerwerwerewr"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! "I tried to use recursive functions, but didn't worked" -- could you share the attempts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for recursive function:

```js
function iter(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
    console.log(k);
    if (k === 'title' || k === 'description') {
      console.log(o[k]);
      o[k] = o[k].en;
      return;
    }
    if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      iter(o[k]);
    }
  });
}
iter(obj);
```

This is a modified version of: [another SO answer :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596909/javascript-iterate-over-deep-nested-object-and-change-certain-unknown-values)

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token :

Comment: can you please update your question first to post the solution you have tried?